# jsonDecode DecodingError when trying to read feed

Tags: ios, getstream-io

I was trying to integrate getstream to my app and i need some help with jsonDecode error that i am getting.

Here are the steps that i took:
1.Create a new feedgroup manually called `allevents`

2.My backend was able to create a new feed called `bday_11` inside all events.

3. I created 2 users `ameet` and `ramya` from my backend and had them add activity. Then using the follow api, i made bday_11 follow both `ameet` and `ramya`.
4. When i manually do bday_11.get(), i am able to see the activities as expected

```
In [86]: bday_11.get()
Out[86]:
{u'duration': u'22.46ms',
 u'next': '',
 u'results': [{u'actor': u'chris',
   u'foreign_id': u'picture:10',
   u'id': u'a0febe54-bfad-11e9-9361-0a286b200b2e',
   u'message': u'Beautiful bird!',
   u'object': u'picture:10',
   u'origin': u'user:ameet',
   u'target': '',
   u'time': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 15, 22, 40, 6, 280764),
   u'verb': u'add'},
  {u'actor': u'chris',
   u'foreign_id': u'picture:10',
   u'id': u'96919914-bfad-11e9-933c-0a286b200b2e',
   u'message': u'Beautiful bird!',
   u'object': u'picture:10',
   u'origin': u'user:ramya',
   u'target': '',
   u'time': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 15, 22, 39, 48, 788252),
   u'verb': u'add'}]}
```

Now on the client side this is how I initialize the client on AppDelegate. This is a modification of your existing demo project with our feed parameters

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Setup Stream Client.

    Client.config = .init(apiKey: "ehs4s58m3u43",appId: "57260",token:FEED_TOKEN)
```

`//Client.config = .init(apiKey:apiKey, appID:appID,token:FeedToken)`

```
    // Setup Stream user.

    Client.shared.getCurrentUser(typeOf: GetStreamActivityFeed.User.self) { result in

        // Current user is ready. Load timeline feed.

        if result.error == nil, let viewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? ViewController {

            viewController.reloadData()

        }

    }



    return true

}
```

Here's how I attempt to read the created feed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    // Setup a timeline feed presenter.



    let timelineFlatFeed = Client.shared.flatFeed(feedSlug: "allevents",userId: "bday_11")

    presenter = FlatFeedPresenter<GetStreamActivityFeed.Activity>(flatFeed: timelineFlatFeed,

                                                                  reactionTypes: [.likes, .comments])





    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupTextToolBar()

    subscribeForUpdates()

}
```

I seem to be getting the following error in the presenter:

```
❌ jsonDecode("The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.", Optional(Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: 
[CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), 
CodingKeys(stringValue: "actor", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))), 667 bytes)
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Looks like your response JSON is invalid. Is it actually returning with the 'u' char before the keys and values?

Also, could you share you struct to decode the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Stream Feeds has a feature named Enrichment (please check docs [here](https://getstream.io/docs/#enrichment_introduction)), where you can keep your data normalized and use references to objects instead full objects inside activities. On iOS client it's enabled by default and the `Activity` by default use `actor` as `User` object, so the request for activities expecting a JSON object for `actor` key, but it got string `u'actor': u'chris'`. So, if you will use actor as `User` object the parsing will work too. Another way is to disable enrichment and use a custom `Activity` with actor as a string:
`typealias MyActivity = EnrichedActivity<String, String, DefaultReaction>` and

```
presenter = FlatFeedPresenter<MyActivity>(flatFeed: timelineFlatFeed,
                                          reactionTypes: [.likes, .comments])
```